# What would be the best tools to achieve interactive images in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, canvas, mern

I'm building a web application to create character builds from a video game. Most functionality for the character builds has been implemented but I'm not sure how to proceed with the next part.

In game there is a wheel that allows the player to traverse down a graph and build a path to unlock skills. The image for that is here [image]

I'm currently developing using the MERN stack and I was thinking about using KonvaJS to implement this wheel into the game. Some key features of this wheel are:

1. Lines between two nodes light up if they're active (activated by clicking)
2. Lines to available paths dimly light up
3. Hovering over a node shows the tooltip of that node's information
4. Clicking a node selects it
5. The three rings (inner, middle, outer) can be rotated to mix and match nodes

   My question is, what would be the best tool to achieve this functionality on the application?

Comment: Thanks for the down-vote? At least justify it with a comment if what I asked doesn't make sense so I can explain more.

Answer (score 0):

There is another library [FabricJs](http://fabricjs.com/) which handles few stuff by default saving you alot of time. Object transforming tool is build-in feature for Fabric.js. You can quite simply transform, resize and rotate objects. Konva has No such support, so you will have to implement that manually. Hence i would prefer FabricJs!